# Forms and POST using perl

Tags: facebook, perl, forms, http, post

I have this which is supposed to fill the email form on the http://faceoook.com/recover.php
and as you know, you can search by email,name or phone number.
So I am trying to search by email, and get the content of that page after the search has been completed to see whether the profile is found or not, but the code doesn't seem to work.

```
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use LWP::UserAgent;
$email="blabla\@hotmail.com";
my %data=(email=>$email);

my $user_agent = 'Mozilla/6.0';
my $Browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$Browser->agent($user_agent);
$ua=$Browser->post('https://www.facebook.com/recover.php',\%data);
if($ua->content=~/couldn\'t/){        #"couldn't" is part of the message displayed when                
print "Not Found";                    # input doesn't match
}
elsif ($ua->content=~/name/) {
print "Found";
}
else {
print "Not found"; 
}

$result=$ua->content;
open FILE,">","me.txt" or die $!;
print FILE $result;
close FILE;
```

Answer (score 1):

- `use strict`
- make it compile under `strict`
- review the manpage for `LWP::UserAgent`, there's a **problem with your code** that you'll have to discover on your own so you'll remember
- review your variable names in light of the conventions used in the manpage
- review the approach (considering the Facebook has an API, IIRC)
- no need to escape the single quote in the regex

Answer (score 0):

You should post your request to the URL in the action field of the form (while you're using the URL of the page which shows the form).

Also add any hidden field to your `%data`.

Have a look at the HTML code of the page (or use some sort of *form inspector*) to get the correct URL and the hidden fields (javascript code, if present, can further complicate things).

Then `use strict` (and `use warnings` as well) as already said by Lumi.